# Motorola Atrix ADB while docked in webtop

Tags: android, adb, dock, motorola, webtop

Does anyone know if/how I can get my atrix connected to my PC via ADB while its docked? The dock has USB ports if I find a male to male USB cable and run it from dock to PC will it recognize the atrix as connected? Is there no way to do this with a cable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Atrix and your PC are connected to the same network, [adbWireless](http://www.appbrain.com/app/adbwireless-%28widget-version%29/siir.es.adbWireless) will allow you to connect to it with the command `adb connect [IP here]`. It works very well, in my experience. You will need a rooted device, however.